# Parsing complete mathematical expressions with PEG.js

Tags: javascript, parsing, peg, pegjs

I'm trying to extend the example grammar of [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) for parsing mathematical expressions with all the 4 operators for my online BASIC interpreter experiment:

http://www.dantonag.it/basicjs/basicjs.html

but not all the expressions are parsed correctly.

This is my PEG grammar:

```
expression = additive

additive = left:multiplicative atag:("+" / "-") right:additive { return {tag: atag, left:left, right:right}; } / multiplicative

multiplicative = left:primary atag:("*" / "/") right:multiplicative { return {tag: atag, left:left, right:right}; } / primary

primary = number / "(" additive:additive ")" { return additive; }

number = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

It parses correctly expressions like 2*3+1 (giving 7), but not an expression like 2-1-1, that gives 2 instead of 0.

Can you help me improving and debugging this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I've added the "number" rule to the grammar. And yes, my grammar gives as output a recursive structure that is analogue to a parse tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First:  your grammar is missing the `number` rule.  Also, as I'm sure you're aware, running your grammar (after adding `number`) on your example does not give 2, but rather something like a parse tree.  Would you mind updating the question to fix those two issues?

---

**Problem:**
It looks like you've run into associativity.  Associativity comes into play when two operators with the same precedence are competing for an operand.  In your example, `-` is competing with `-` -- so clearly it will have the same precedence as itself -- but associativity will also be important for breaking ties between `+` and `-`, and between `*` and `/`.

I assume that `2*3+1` is parsed correctly because the two operators have different precedences, meaning that associativity does not come into play, and that your grammar correctly implements precedence (although you should note that `2+3*1` is a more standard example for showing that multiplication has higher precedence than addition, since simple left-to-right parsing of `2*3+1` gives the same result as your parser).

I assume you want `-` to be left-associative, but it seems to be right-associative in your grammar, based on this example:

- input:

  ```
  1-2-3
  ```
- output (parsed as `1-(2-3)`):

  ```
  {
     "tag": "-",
     "left": "1",
     "right": {
        "tag": "-",
        "left": "2",
        "right": "3"
     }
  }
  ```

The left associative tree would look like this (from `(1-2)-3`):

```
{
   "tag": "-",
   "left": {
      "tag": "-",
      "left": "1",
      "right": "2"
   },
   "right": "3"
}
```

You should note that your other operators also appear to be right-associative instead of left-.

**Solution:** I don't really know how peg.js works, but some quick googling turned up [this](https://github.com/dmajda/pegjs/blob/master/examples/javascript.pegjs#L735).

Grammar-based solutions to operator precedence and associativity are often pretty nasty (see a [grammar for Python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) for evidence), so you may want to check out [top down] operator precedence parsing for a more flexible and expressive alternative.  Douglas Crockford, Vaughn Pratt, and Annika Aasa have some nice articles on this subject.

Comment: Ok thanks, solved this looking at the example grammar you posted. I think it would have been very hard to come to this solution without an hint!

Answer (score 11):

Matt's answer is the correct one, but on how to implement left-associativity within pegjs:

```
expression = additive

additive
  = first:multiplicative rest:(("+" / "-") multiplicative)+ {
    return rest.reduce(function(memo, curr) {
      return {atag: curr[0], left: memo, right: curr[1]};
    }, first);
  }
  / multiplicative

multiplicative
  = first:primary rest:(("*" / "/") primary)+ {
    return rest.reduce(function(memo, curr) {
      return {atag: curr[0], left: memo, right: curr[1]};
    }, first);
  }
  / primary

primary
  = number
  / "(" additive:additive ")" { return additive; }

number
  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

The [javascript.pegjs](https://github.com/dmajda/pegjs/blob/master/examples/javascript.pegjs) example Matt links to uses a similar method. The key is to process strings of operations with the same precedence as a list, which allows you to build your tree with the correct associativity.

Comment: The use of `reduce` to roll up repeat expressions is really elegant. Great answer!